# Toyota Corolla CE110 -1996 Airbag indicator won't lit No error either

Tags: corolla, supplemental-restraint-system

This car does not indicate the airbag, when car starts it suppose to lit and turn off. But that does not happen and since that might be something to do with indicator I tried changing the indicator. But that did not helped.

Since indicator does not lit at all, there should not be any error either, as if there is an error it should indicate it.

Any advise regarding this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities I can think of for you.

First, depending on the year of your car and how the bag(s) are set up, there might not be a light. My son had an older Jeep Cherokee which had a mechanically activated air bag. Because it was mechanical, it didn't have a light.

Second, the bulb in the dash may be burnt out. To fix, you'd have to take the dash apart and replace the bulb.

Comment: There is a light... and it's close to the ABS indicator which works fine. And I have replaced the indicator and still it does not works.

Comment: Have you checked the system with a scanner capable of "seeing" the SRS? I know in Virginia where I live, this is one of the things checked by the safety inspector on a yearly basis.

Comment: No.. I haven't done that. I will try to find a scanner but I'm not sure how much i might have to pay for..

Comment: A decent scanner would cost you around $100 or so, at least one which can read SRS.